# Some of the outputs are not shown or displayed as "None"

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is:

```
t = int(input())
nentry = int(input())
def nitems():
    for number in range(nentry):
        items = input()[:10] * number       
        print(items)

n = nitems()
```

My code works like this:

Input

```
2
2
Foo
Bar
```

Output

```
(Blankspace)
 Bar 
(Blankspace)
```

And I wanted the output to be:

```
Foo
Bar
```

Comment: Try `items = input()` instead.

Comment: woah dude that was quick xD 
Thanks! Happy coding!

Comment: you aren't returning anything from the function so Python will implicitly return the `None` you see printed. Why `input()[:10] * number`? `number` is zero at the first iteration, so an empty string is returned.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. :)

Comment: I'll try to be more careful next time when making a script and troubleshooting